# Is there any way to programmatically back out of an W10m app rather than exiting it?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Application.Current.Exit() exits the app programmatically, but I need to simulate the same effect as when you press back out of you app, ie usually suspending it. Is it possible?

(yes I know you usually shouldn't mess around with this but it's for a very specific purpose)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to exit an app programmatically without terminating it.